# Dependency Injection with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The biggest benefit of dependency injection I have found is being able to replace the implementation of a service throughout my entire app in one line at the composition root.

Is there a way of doing this using React hooks?

It seems that when using a hook, eg useHook(), you're binding tightly to a specific implementation, and it's a manual process to find and switch out all the implementations, which is further complicated by useHooks() appearing at arbitrary points in the component.

My current solution is to use a React Context to make the composition root availiable to everything as required, which seems to be working well, but with many touting Hooks as a DI framework I am wondering if I've missed something.

Comment: hooks and context are two different things. Hooks are equivalent of HOCs and not context. Context still remains at the heart of many libraries like Router, React-Redux

Comment: hooks and hocs are two totally different things: hoc to compose behavior, hook to reuse logic. @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: @Incepter Hooks were means to substitute HOCs is what I meant. And I agree that is the purpose of only custom hooks. There are out of the box hooks too

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [container pattern](https://blog.bitsrc.io/implementing-the-container-pattern-using-react-hooks-f490a8492d05). Create a container which is responsible for using the hooks and pass the results to the component.

```
const Component = (props) => {
    return <div>{ props.data }</div>;
};

const Container = (props) => {
    const data = useHook();

    return <Component data={data} />;
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately that would not be very practical in a large application, so I don't think this is the solution the OP is looking for.

Comment: I disagree with @VoY, I think creating a clear separation between pure presentation components and the data layer is essential in a large application if you want to have any ability to test or change anything